# Typescript virtual folder to reference external library

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wanting to create an Angular library with all of my generic components, directives, functions, pipes, services, etc. to share with separate projects.  I would rather not create an actual library app with its own dependencies, index.js files, etc. and have to keep track of versioning and all that.  I simply just want to reference an external set of files from my root folder.  It seems this should be common practice for local development.  I can imagine it working this way - in your root folder (src), you add a virtual folder and set the path of that folder to wherever your library is.  Done.  Everything else works just as normal.  It requires no build, no versioning, and the compiler just pulls from the provided path.  This would make code consolidation so much easier and simpler for local development.

Can this be done?  Are there any VS Code extensions that allow this?

Comment: It could be done fairly simply on Linux or Mac OS by using "soft links", i.e. the "ln -s" command. I have no idea if this is possible on Windows.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek In windows it would be `mklink /D C:\LinkToFolder C:\Users\Name\OriginalFolder`

Comment: I tried mklink already and that works fine.. until you compile.  Any imports in the virtual folder files are relative to THAT file, which of course they can't be found - it ruins the relative paths.